# How to initialise a nested table collection which resides inside a PL/SQL Record?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Friends,

Hope you can help.

What I am trying to achieve is to use a collection type(s) that can be accessed either inside and outside of PL/SQL so that an external program can declare a type of this collection and work with it's contents.

The collection will contain some scaler and one composite datatype.

Using the scott schema as an example, the goal is that each record within the collection should contain the department information and within the same record a collection containing the employee information for that department.

I have got the output I require when using PL/SQL associative arrays but they can only be used from with PL/SQL.

When I convert the code to use another type of collection, nested table, I receive a `ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection`  Which is because I haven't initialised the collection held within the record.

Is it possible to achieve this using this design? Or (as I increasing feel!) have I gone down the wrong path?

Two code samples follow.

Firstly the one that works with PL/SQL associative arrays:

```
DECLARE

   TYPE emp_tab_type IS TABLE OF emp%ROWTYPE
        INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    TYPE dept_emp_rec IS RECORD (dept_id    dept.deptno%TYPE,
                                 dept_name    dept.dname%TYPE,
                                 dept_loc    dept.loc%TYPE,    
                                 emp_data   emp_tab_type);  

    TYPE dept_emp_tab_type IS TABLE OF dept_emp_rec
        INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    l_dept_emp_tab    dept_emp_tab_type;

    CURSOR dept_cur IS
        SELECT d.*
        FROM dept d
        ORDER BY  d.deptno;

    CURSOR emps_cur (p_dept_id IN NUMBER ) IS 
        SELECT e.*
        FROM emp e
        WHERE e.deptno = p_dept_id
        ORDER BY e.ename;

    j   PLS_INTEGER := 1;

    k   PLS_INTEGER;

BEGIN


    FOR dept_rec IN dept_cur 
    LOOP

       -- populate dept data
       l_dept_emp_tab(j).dept_id := dept_rec.deptno;

       -- other assignment statements

       dbms_output.put_line('dept no ' ||   l_dept_emp_tab(j).dept_id);

       -- populate emp data
       k := 1;             

       FOR emp_row_rec IN emps_cur(dept_rec.deptno)
       LOOP

           l_dept_emp_tab(j).emp_data(k).empno := emp_row_rec.empno;

           -- other assignment statements

           dbms_output.put_line( l_dept_emp_tab(j).emp_data(k).empno);

           k := k + 1;

       END LOOP;

       j := j + 1;

    END LOOP;


END;
```

This is the example using nested tables that DOESN'T work

```
DECLARE

   TYPE emp_tab_type IS TABLE OF emp%ROWTYPE;
        --INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    TYPE dept_emp_rec IS RECORD (dept_id    dept.deptno%TYPE,
                                 dept_name    dept.dname%TYPE,
                                 dept_loc    dept.loc%TYPE,    
                                 emp_data   emp_tab_type);  

    TYPE dept_emp_tab_type IS TABLE OF dept_emp_rec;
        --INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    l_dept_emp_tab    dept_emp_tab_type := dept_emp_tab_type(); 

    CURSOR dept_cur IS
        SELECT d.*
        FROM dept d
        ORDER BY  d.deptno;

    CURSOR emps_cur (p_dept_id IN NUMBER ) IS 
        SELECT e.*
        FROM emp e
        WHERE e.deptno = p_dept_id
        ORDER BY e.ename;

    j   PLS_INTEGER := 1;

    k   PLS_INTEGER;

BEGIN


    FOR dept_rec IN dept_cur 
    LOOP

      l_dept_emp_tab.EXTEND;

       -- populate dept data
       l_dept_emp_tab(j).dept_id := dept_rec.deptno;

       -- other assignment statements

       dbms_output.put_line('dept no ' ||   l_dept_emp_tab(j).dept_id);

       -- populate emp data
       k := 1;             

       FOR emp_row_rec IN emps_cur(dept_rec.deptno)
       LOOP

           l_dept_emp_tab(j).emp_data(k).empno := emp_row_rec.empno;

           -- other assignment statements

           dbms_output.put_line( l_dept_emp_tab(j).emp_data(k).empno);

           k := k + 1;

       END LOOP;

       j := j + 1;

    END LOOP;


END;
```

I am using Oracle Enterprise Edition 10.2.0.4

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed getting the `ORA-06531` error because you haven't initialised the collections within each record.  To do this, try adding the line

```
       l_dept_emp_tab(j).emp_data := emp_tab_type();
```

to the other assignments to fields of `l_dept_emp_tab(j)`.

You'll also need to add a call to `l_dept_emp_tab(j).emp_data.EXTEND` within the inner loop, to make space for the new entry about to be added.  Insert this above all the assignments within the inner loop.  If you don't add this, you'll get an `ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count` error.

You seem to be handling the outer nested table type (`dept_emp_tab_type`) correctly, by calling its constructor (in the `DECLARE` section) and by calling `EXTEND` to grow the nested table.  All you need to do is to do the same for each instance of the inner nested table type,`emp_tab_type` .

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different way, this accomplishes everything pretty much within a query (do note it requires the types to be created outside of the block)

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm

Creation and cleanup of table and types used

```
/*
CREATE  TABLE EMP (ENAME VARCHAR2(50) , DEPTNO NUMBER, empno number);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('m1e',1,1);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('m2e',1,2);
insert into emp values('m3e',2,3);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('m2e',2,4);
insert into emp values('m3e',3,5);

CREATE TABLE DEPT(deptno NUMBER, dname VARCHAR2(50), loc VARCHAR2(50));
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES(1 ,'portland','tt');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES(2 ,'astoria','tt');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES(3 ,'eugene','tt');
```

Creation of types (note this is not within the package/block so that it is available to SQL)

```
---
drop type emptable force;
DROP TYPE EMP_TAB_TYPE force;
drop type emptable ;
DROP TYPE DEPT_EMP_REC force;
drop type dep_emp_rec_table force;
DROP TABLE DEPT;
drop table emp;

*/
```

Now create the types outside the package/block so the types are available to SQL

```
create or replace  TYPE emp_tab_type as object (ENAME VARCHAR2(50) , DEPTNO NUMBER);
create or replace type emptable as table of emp_tab_type ;
    CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE DEPT_EMP_REC AS OBJECT (
                                 DEPT_ID    NUMBER,
                                 dept_name    varchar2(50),
                                 dept_loc    varchar2(50),    
                                 emp_data   emptable);  
create or replace type dep_emp_rec_table as table of dept_emp_rec;
```

Now we can directly select the types into the query (note the use of the [cast/MULTISET](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm))

```
SELECT 
                  DEPT_EMP_REC(
                                deptno, 
                                dname , 
                                loc , 
                         CAST(MULTISET(SELECT ENAME, DEPTNO
                                         FROM EMP e
                                         WHERE e.DEPTNO = d.deptno)
                              AS emptable))
  FROM DEPT D ;
/
DEPT_EMP_REC(DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC,CAST(MULTISET(SELECTENAME,DEPTNOFROMEMPEWHEREE.DEPTNO=D.DEPTNO)ASEMPTABLE))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              DEPT_EMP_REC(1,'portland','tt',EMPTABLE(EMP_TAB_TYPE('m1e',1),EMP_TAB_TYPE('m2e',1)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
DEPT_EMP_REC(2,'astoria','tt',EMPTABLE(EMP_TAB_TYPE('m3e',2),EMP_TAB_TYPE('m2e',2)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DEPT_EMP_REC(3,'eugene','tt',EMPTABLE(EMP_TAB_TYPE('m3e',3)))
```

Now the block is a bit simpler (putting it all together)

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE


p_dep_emp_rec_table dep_emp_rec_table;

BEGIN
     SELECT
        DEPT_EMP_REC( 
           DEPTNO, 
           DNAME, 
           LOC, 
           CAST( MULTISET
                   (   
                    SELECT 
                            ENAME, 
                            DEPTNO 
                       FROM EMP E 
                      WHERE E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO
                ) AS EMPTABLE ) 
            )
      BULK COLLECT INTO p_dep_emp_rec_table
       FROM
        DEPT d ;


   FOR I IN P_DEP_EMP_REC_TABLE.FIRST..P_DEP_EMP_REC_TABLE.LAST LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I || ':' || P_DEP_EMP_REC_TABLE(I).DEPT_ID || '|' || P_DEP_EMP_REC_TABLE(I).DEPT_NAME || '|' ||  P_DEP_EMP_REC_TABLE(I).DEPT_LOC);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------');
      FOR J IN P_DEP_EMP_REC_TABLE(I).EMP_DATA.FIRST..P_DEP_EMP_REC_TABLE(I).EMP_DATA.LAST LOOP
        NULL;
        dbms_output.put_line(P_DEP_EMP_REC_TABLE(i).emp_data(j).ENAME || '/' || P_DEP_EMP_REC_TABLE(i).emp_data(j).DEPTNO);
      end loop;
   END LOOP;
END;


anonymous block completed
1:1|portland|tt
-----------------------
m1e/1
m2e/1
2:2|astoria|tt
-----------------------
m3e/2
m2e/2
3:3|eugene|tt
-----------------------
m3e/3
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for taking the time to provide an alternative. Very much appreciated!